# what is the wrong in this LinQ?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, linq-to-sql

This is my Linq query. This works fine. The problem is If any one have no Last name in table, then the row is not show in the result. I want if any one have no last name then it will be User_Name= First Name +" ".

```
var ShowFiles = from cm in db.Contact_Masters
                        join ta in db.Topic_Accesses on cm.Contact_ID equals ta.Contact_ID
                        join RelMess in db.Rel_Topics_Messages on ta.Topic_ID equals RelMess.Topic_ID
                        join Messages in db.Messages on RelMess.Message_ID equals Messages.Message_ID
                        join Files in db.Files on Messages.Message_ID equals Files.Message_ID
                        join FileType in db.Lkup_Files_Extensions on Files.TypeID equals FileType.TypeID
                        join FileVersion in db.File_Versions on Files.File_ID equals FileVersion.File_ID
                        join pcf in db.Contact_Personals on Messages.Contact_ID equals pcf.Contact_ID
                        where pcf.Personal_Type == new Guid("30102333-2104-40D7-8913-DC9048225D12") // Personal_Type = First Name ID
                        join pcl in db.Contact_Personals on Messages.Contact_ID equals pcl.Contact_ID
                        where pcl.Personal_Type == new Guid("9058F268-B707-4B0A-86E5-26E83A4BC1F5") // Personal_Type = Last Name ID 

                        where cm.Contact_ID == new Guid(ContactID) && ids.Contains(RelMess.Topic_ID)// parameters
                        && FileVersion.IsActive == true && Messages.IsActive == true && FileVersion.Version_ID == (from FileV in db.File_Versions
                                                                                                                   where FileV.File_ID == Files.File_ID 
                                                                                                                   && FileV.Message_ID == Messages.Message_ID 
                                                                                                                   && FileV.IsActive == true
                                                                                                                   select FileV.Version_ID).Max()
                        select new
                        {
                            File_Name = Convert.ToString(Files.File_Name),
                            Version_ID = Convert.ToString(FileVersion.Version_ID),
                            File_Size = Convert.ToString(FileVersion.File_Size),
                            Created = Convert.ToString(FileVersion.Created),
                            Type = FileType.Type,
                            File_URL = FileVersion.File_URL,
                            File_ID = Convert.ToString(FileVersion.File_ID),
                            User_Name = pcf.Value + " " + pcl.Value  
                        };
```

Thanks
Nahid

Comment: Just some wild guessing: If the last name is not in the database (cause it is `null`) is then the `pcl.Personal_Type` set to the given guid?

Answer (score 5):

Try the following:

```
User_Name = pcf.Value + 
    (pcf.Value != null && pcf.Value.Trim() != string.Empty ? " " + pcl.Value : "")
```

**Edit: Removed the usage of IsNullOrWhiteSpace, thanks Jacek**

Comment: Does that really translate to SQL?

Comment: It should do yeah, if IsNullOrWhiteSpace isn't supported by Linq-To-Sql then you can just mimic what it does by changing everything in the brackets to: (pcl.Value != null && pcl.Value != string.Empty ? " " + pcl.Value : "")

Comment: This should work, as opposed to IsNullOrWhiteSpace(): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606979/string-isnullorwhitespace-in-linq-expression

Comment: Thanks Jacek, I'll update my answer :)